# an inappropriate symbol appears in the response

Tags: java, php, android

I created a registration and login code that connects to Android Studio, but I face a login that cannot, after I checked with Postman that my login and register was successful but apparently I found a strange symbol appeared in the response.

{
"status": true,
"message": "Login Berhasil",
"data": {
"user_id": 3,
"username": "admin2\n",
"name": "admin2"
}
}

the strange symbol I mean is the "\n" that appears in the username section

I've been trying to find where this symbol is located but can't find it, I hope here I can find a solution.

Comment: The symbol "\n" is an escape character for new line. This indicates in text that the next characters after this symbol is written in the next line. Usually the keyboard shortcuts for this is just pressing our "Enter" key. Maybe when the username is added and then the user presses "Enter" to submit the login form its registering this symbol.

Comment: VERY HELPFUL I found the problem like u said when I register the username I pressed"enter", thank you

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a Java problem? Please share the code involved, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

That's an escaped newline character inside the string. Unescaped newlines are invalid inside JSON strings.

Note that a newline may not be visible is there is no further text in a UI, so it may be not obvious to a user.

Comment: mean is this a normal thing? sorry to ask like this I'm a beginner

Comment: It is expected that if a string has special characters not allowed by the JSON specification they have to escaped. You should get familiar with the specification. If that character was intended for this particular string is something that you should ask to whoever provided that JSON document.

Comment: VERY HELPFUL I found the problem,  when I register the username I pressed"enter", thank you aled